# Function to Get Item. Text based Python Game

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python and working on a texted based game. I am having trouble figuring out how to create the function to 'get_item'. Right now when running the code, when the 'get_item' function is called, the location and directions is stored in the 'inventory' dict. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import sys

# Dictionary of areas

rooms = {
    'Main Street': {'North': 'Run Down Burger Shack', 'South': 'Strange Hut', 'East': 'Eerie House',
                    'West': 'Abandoned Motel'},
    'Strange Hut': {'North': 'Main Street', 'East': 'Back Room', 'Item': 'Great Staff'},
    'Back Room': {'West': 'Strange Hut', 'Item': 'Shield'},
    'Abandoned Motel': {'East': 'Main Street', 'Item': 'Duct Tape'},
    'Run Down Burger Shack': {'South': 'Main Street', 'East': 'Burned Down Car', 'Item': 'Mysterious Burger'},
    'Burned Down Car': {'West': 'Run Down Burger Shack', 'Item': 'Sharp Metal Piece'},
    'Eerie House': {'West': 'Main Street', 'North': 'Red Room', 'Item': 'Flashlight'},
    'Red Room': {'South': 'Eerie House', 'Villain': 'Serial Killer'}
}

inventory = {}
# Starting location of the player
location = 'Main Street'
# No direction, will prompt for it
playerMove = ''


def get_item(playerMove):
    for playerMove in rooms[location]:
        rooms[location].pop('Item')
        inventory.update(rooms[location])
        return inventory


def playerinfo(location, inventory, rooms):
    #  Display current inventory and location
    print('Inventory:', inventory)
    print(f"You are at the : \033[1;31;40m{location}\033[1;32;40m")


#  Introduction to the game
while True:
    # Change the color of the text
    print('\n\033[1;32;40mWelcome to the abandoned city of Winchester')
    play = input('Would you like to explore? y/n: ').strip().capitalize()
    #  Branches to continue with game
    if play == 'Y':
        print('At any point in the game if you would like\n'
              'to quit just type "exit" to exit the game')
        print('Good luck and stay safe!\n')
        break
    elif play == 'N':
        print("Good! You wouldn't survive anyway!")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('Invalid input')


#  Game Loop
while playerMove != 'Exit':
    playerinfo(location, inventory, rooms)
    #  Shows the user possible inputs
    choices = rooms[location].keys()
    print("Possible Directions:", *choices)
    #  Ask for user input, strip away whitespace and capitalize input
    playerMove = input("What would you like to do? ").strip().capitalize()
    #  Change color of text
    print(f'You chose: \033[1;31;40m{playerMove}\033[1;32;40m\n')
    #  System exit if user inputs 'Exit'
    if playerMove == 'Exit':
        print('You exited the game')
        sys.exit()
    #  Call function to retrieve item
    if playerMove == 'Item':
        get_item(playerMove)
    #  Call function to move between rooms
    if playerMove in rooms[location]:
        location = rooms[location][playerMove]
    else:
        print('Invalid movement command.')
```

Comment: What is `get_item` supposed to do?

Comment: get_item is supposed to retrieve an item in each particular room except for the starting room and add it to the users inventory while also removing the same item from the 'rooms' dict  before reaching the final room to fight the boss.

Comment: Why does get_item have a loop with an unconditional return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before getting to the function `get_item` first a few other things to change:

- `inventory` should not be a dict, but a set (of found items). So initialise it as `inventory = set()`
- The time to call `get_item` should not be just before *leaving* a room, but at the time you just *enter* it. So call this function as the first statement inside the game loop and just call it unconditionally. The condition can be put in the function itself.
- Don't pass `playerMove` as argument, as that doesn't really help to know where you are and what items are there. Instead pass `rooms[location]` as argument, which is the dict with the potential `Item` key.

The function itself can then be:

```
def get_item(locationInfo):
    if 'Item' in locationInfo:
        print("You find here a " + locationInfo['Item'])
        inventory.add(locationInfo.pop('Item'))
```

So the complete code, without changing anything else, becomes:

```
import sys

# Dictionary of areas

rooms = {
    'Main Street': {'North': 'Run Down Burger Shack', 'South': 'Strange Hut', 'East': 'Eerie House',
                    'West': 'Abandoned Motel'},
    'Strange Hut': {'North': 'Main Street', 'East': 'Back Room', 'Item': 'Great Staff'},
    'Back Room': {'West': 'Strange Hut', 'Item': 'Shield'},
    'Abandoned Motel': {'East': 'Main Street', 'Item': 'Duct Tape'},
    'Run Down Burger Shack': {'South': 'Main Street', 'East': 'Burned Down Car', 'Item': 'Mysterious Burger'},
    'Burned Down Car': {'West': 'Run Down Burger Shack', 'Item': 'Sharp Metal Piece'},
    'Eerie House': {'West': 'Main Street', 'North': 'Red Room', 'Item': 'Flashlight'},
    'Red Room': {'South': 'Eerie House', 'Villain': 'Serial Killer'}
}

inventory = set()
# Starting location of the player
location = 'Main Street'
# No direction, will prompt for it
playerMove = ''


def get_item(locationInfo):
    if 'Item' in locationInfo:
        print("You find here a " + locationInfo['Item'])
        inventory.add(locationInfo.pop('Item'))


def playerinfo(location, inventory, rooms):
    #  Display current inventory and location
    print('Inventory:', inventory)
    print(f"You are at the : \033[1;31;40m{location}\033[1;32;40m")


#  Introduction to the game
while True:
    # Change the color of the text
    print('\n\033[1;32;40mWelcome to the abandoned city of Winchester')
    play = input('Would you like to explore? y/n: ').strip().capitalize()
    #  Branches to continue with game
    if play == 'Y':
        print('At any point in the game if you would like\n'
              'to quit just type "exit" to exit the game')
        print('Good luck and stay safe!\n')
        break
    elif play == 'N':
        print("Good! You wouldn't survive anyway!")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('Invalid input')


#  Game Loop
while playerMove != 'Exit':
    #  Call function to retrieve item
    get_item(rooms[location])
    playerinfo(location, inventory, rooms)
    #  Shows the user possible inputs
    choices = rooms[location].keys()
    print("Possible Directions:", *choices)
    #  Ask for user input, strip away whitespace and capitalize input
    playerMove = input("What would you like to do? ").strip().capitalize()
    #  Change color of text
    print(f'You chose: \033[1;31;40m{playerMove}\033[1;32;40m\n')
    #  System exit if user inputs 'Exit'
    if playerMove == 'Exit':
        print('You exited the game')
        sys.exit()
    #  Call function to move between rooms
    if playerMove in rooms[location]:
        location = rooms[location][playerMove]
    else:
        print('Invalid movement command.')
```

There is much else that could be improved, but with these changes your question should be resolved.